# Iterating through columns in pandas while applying different functions to each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I want to iterate though each column of a certain data frame, while at the same time applying different functions to each column. If every function is different for each column, is there a way to automate the code and not write N lines of code, where N is the total number of columns?

Comment: This is quite vague. Use a loop? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: You just didnt understand my question. I could use a loop if every function for each column was identical or at least related. But if for every column there is a different function to apply, i dont see any way to automate this task.

Comment: You could use a dictionary to map each column name to a function. That may not be possible, though, it depends on the specifics of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `agg`, as in :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(3), "b": range(3,6)})
df.agg({"a": sum, "b": np.mean})
```

Comment: Yeah thats what i'm talking about. If i have a very large number of columns and for each column i want to apply a different function, i think the only way of applying them is just writing them all. Maybe it was a dumb question to ask, since if I have to apply N different functions which are in no way related, there is no way to automate the task and NOT write every function. Sorry